# "No destination configuration registered" - WCF/SAP integration using SAP nCo3 (SAP .NET Connectior 3.0)

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, exception, iis-express, sap-dotnet-connector

When I try to call a WCF service I developed I get this error message: "Method or operation is not implemented".

Let me explain the scenario I'm facing and them I'll give you more details, the code and etc:

I'm developing a WCf service in .NET framework 4.0 in a Windows 8/Visual Studio 2012 machine. 
The WCF service will be accessed from a mobile application developed in .NET compact framework 2.0 (Dev environment: a Virtual Machine running Windows XP service pack 3, Visual Studio 2008, Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional Emulator).

The WCF service is using the SAP .NET Conector (SAPnCO) version 3.0.

When I run the service using VS integrated IIS or IIS8, everything goes fine: I can test the service, access it from a test console application and can access it from Windows Mobile Emulator.

However, we where about to start some preliminar tests with the final users and we still didn`t have a proper server to deploy the WCF application, so I had to make a contingency server using Windows XP and IIS express 7.5 (I was not able to make it work on IIS 5.1).

I know that IIS Express is for local access only, but I followed this tutorial to open ti to the LAN: [TUTORIAL](http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx).

Doing so I can acess the service signature via browser and see the WSDL file.

Everytime i try to acess the service I get the error message "Method or operation is not implemented". I`ve been looking for some similar problem over the internet for the past 4 hours without success.

Here`s what I managed to do so far:

- Host a default WCF sample service on IIS Express 7.5 and use the service remotely: ok;
- Reduce the scope of the original service to the minimal only: still get the same error;

So, I still don't know what can be causing this or how to solve it. I kindly request for your help, please!

Here`s my code:

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="SAP.Middleware.Connector">
      <sectionGroup name="ClientSettings">
        <section name="DestinationConfiguration" type="SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationConfiguration, sapnco"/>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <SAP.Middleware.Connector>
    <ClientSettings>
      <DestinationConfiguration>
        <destinations>
          <add NAME="QA" USER="XX" PASSWD="XX" CLIENT="XX" LANG="XX" ASHOST="XX" SYSNR="XX" MAX_POOL_SIZE="XX" IDLE_TIMEOUT="XX"/>
        </destinations>
      </DestinationConfiguration>
    </ClientSettings>
  </SAP.Middleware.Connector>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

**SERVICE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

using SAP.Middleware.Connector;

namespace WCFCriarOT
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public string CriarOT(int areaSelecionada, int nlenr, string codMaterial, int qtdMAterial)
        {
            try
            {


                string vltyp = "", vlpla = "";

                switch (areaSelecionada)
                {
                    case 1:
                        vltyp = "902";
                        vlpla = "GR-ZONE";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        vltyp = "901";
                        vlpla = "GFI-ZONE";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        vltyp = "904";
                        vlpla = "DEVOLUCAO";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                RfcDestination SapRfcDestination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("QA");
                RfcRepository SapRfcRepository = SapRfcDestination.Repository;
                IRfcFunction FCriarOT = SapRfcRepository.CreateFunction("ZWM001");

                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_LGNUM", "WM1");
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_BWLVS", "999");
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_MATNR", codMaterial);
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_WERKS", "120");
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_LGORT", "0001");
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_ANFME", qtdMAterial);
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_SQUIT", "");
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_VLTYP", vltyp);
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_VLPLA", vlpla);
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_VLENR", "");
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_NLTYP", "");
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_NLPLA", "");
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_NLENR", nlenr.ToString().PadLeft(20, '0'));
                FCriarOT.SetValue("I_BNAME", "PAGOTR"); // receber os dados do login posteriormente

                FCriarOT.Invoke(SapRfcDestination);

                if (Convert.ToInt32(FCriarOT.GetValue("E_RETURN")) == 1)
                {
                    IRfcTable RfcReturn = FCriarOT.GetTable("T_MSG");
                    RfcReturn.CurrentIndex = 0;



                    return "1";
                }
                else
                {


                    return "0";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();

            }
        }
    }
```

**SERVICE SIGNATURE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFCriarOT
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        // Contrato para a operação "Criar OT"
        [OperationContract]
        string CriarOT(int areaSelecionada, int nlenr, string codMaterial, int qtdMAterial);

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
    }
```

**Exception**

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=O método ou a operação não está implementada.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at testeDoTeste1.ServiceReference1.IService1.CriarOT(Int32 areaSelecionada, Int32 nlenr, String codMaterial, Int32 qtdMAterial)
       at testeDoTeste1.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.CriarOT(Int32 areaSelecionada, Int32 nlenr, String codMaterial, Int32 qtdMAterial) in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\testeDoTeste1\testeDoTeste1\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 119
       at testeDoTeste1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\testeDoTeste1\testeDoTeste1\Program.cs:line 16
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

If I have failed in provide all necessary information, please, let me know: I will provide anything I can. I really need and apretiate all your help! Tks a lot!

**--------------**

**UPDATE 1**

Since the WEB.CONFIG file is the only piece of the service that is edited to make the WCF service work with IIS Express I think this can (evetually) be the source of trouble. I`m posting the original WEB.CONFIG file, without the edits hoping that this can help someone spot the problem!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="SAP.Middleware.Connector">
      <sectionGroup name="ClientSettings">
        <section name="DestinationConfiguration" type="SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationConfiguration, sapnco"/>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <SAP.Middleware.Connector>
    <ClientSettings>
      <DestinationConfiguration>
        <destinations>
          <add NAME="QA" USER="XX" PASSWD="XX" CLIENT="XX" LANG="XX" ASHOST="XX" SYSNR="XX" MAX_POOL_SIZE="XX" IDLE_TIMEOUT="XX"/>
        </destinations>
      </DestinationConfiguration>
    </ClientSettings>
  </SAP.Middleware.Connector>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**--------------**

**UPDATE 2**

Found a new error, but it`s still fuzzy to me: "{"Cannot get destination QA -- no destination configuration registered"}". This destination works fine in dev, so why it is not working on IIS Express?

Anyways, here`s the complete exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Cannot get destination QA -- no destination configuration registered
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at testeDoTeste1.ServiceReference1.IService1.CriarOT(Int32 areaSelecionada, Int32 nlenr, String codMaterial, Int32 qtdMAterial)
       at testeDoTeste1.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.CriarOT(Int32 areaSelecionada, Int32 nlenr, String codMaterial, Int32 qtdMAterial) in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\testeDoTeste1\testeDoTeste1\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 119
       at testeDoTeste1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\testeDoTeste1\testeDoTeste1\Program.cs:line 16
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

**--------------**

Comment: What happens if you comment out the catch-then-re-throw-as-notimpl part?

Comment: Sorry, I didn`t quite understood it: Your suggestion is for me to comment the try-catch part?

Comment: Yes, exactly - I suspect you might be trapping (hiding) the real underlying issue.

Comment: Great idea! I`m out of work right now: I need to get some sleep. However, I`ll return ASAP and run some tests without the Try-catch statement and post the results! After some testing and wondering I have a strong belief that the problem can be the WEB.CONFIG, because he`s the only piece of code that needs adjustments to the service to work with IIS Express. However, I can`t figure out what is it... I`ll edit the original post to show the original WEB.CONFIG file.

Comment: Good general lesson, whether it solves this problem. Or not: don't hide exceptions from yourself.

Comment: Found a new error, as you said, but it`s still fuzzy to me: "{"Cannot get destination QA -- no destination configuration registered"}". This destination works fine in dev, so why it is not working on IIS Express?

Comment: Still can`t find a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found, this exception occurs if sapnco assembly is not loaded. Try to set referenced SAP assemblies to Copy local: True.

It is not ideal solution, but it has worked for me well.

Comment: That did the trick for me, even though Sap connector was installed in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by moving the configSections' section to the top of the app.config. Maybe the 'configSections' must be the first child section of configuration.

See here too:
[Parameter 'sectionGroupName' is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450503/parameter-sectiongroupname-is-invalid)